# uploading and parsing a CSV file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, csv, file-io

My current environment is using Javascript, HTML, File API to upload files. At the moment, I have been research on how to read a File API-uploaded CSV file such as:

```
Id,Event type,Start,Stop,Timezone,Precision,Entity,Momentum,Financial positive sentiment,Financial negative sentiment,General positive sentiment,General negative sentiment,Fragment,Document category,Document title,Document url,Document published,Source name,Source media type,Source topic,Source country,Attributes
GQcBzYAEAJL,Buybacks,2/7/2013 19:00,2/8/2013 18:59,America/New_York,day,,0.25,0.22,0.44,0.22,0,"Share buy back DMGT's strong operational cash flow and disciplined management of our portfolio of businesses has resulted in a net debt to EBITDA ratio of 1.6, falling to well below our stated internal limit of 2.4 times.",Business_Finance,Daily Mail & General : Preliminary Results 2011/12,http://www.investegate.co.uk/article.aspx?id=20121122070000PDC35,11/22/2012 3:03,Investegate.co.uk,Niche,None,United Kingdom,company:Daily Mail & General Trust|fragment_count:1|inherited_locations:[DMGT]
GQf0LxASVpP,Company Layoffs,1/31/2013 19:00,2/1/2013 18:59,America/New_York,day,,0.03,0,0.31,0,0,"As a result, Quadel will need to reduce its workforce by 64 employees beginning on or about Feb. 1, concluding no later than 14 days afterward.",Labor,Florida Quadel Consulting to lay off 64 in Miami,http://feeds.bizjournals.com/~r/bizj_southflorida/~3/bdu_17A5w6M/florida-quadel-consulting-to-lay-off.html,12/3/2012 14:50,Bizjournals.com (8237),Niche,None,United States of America,authors:[Shaun Bevan]|company:Quadel Consulting Corp|fragment_count:1|status:planned
GQYBsgACGKI,Company Layoffs,1/30/2013 19:00,1/31/2013 18:59,America/New_York,day,,0.46,0,0.26,0,0,"The parent group unveiled a ""reduction of 4.500 jobs to safeguard around 15.500 posts across the airline"" -- meaning Iberia was on course to shed almost one quarter of its staff.",Business_Finance,"Iberia survival plan: slash quarter of jobs, cut 15% network and downsize fleet",http://en.mercopress.com/2012/11/10/iberia-survival-plan-slash-quarter-of-jobs-cut-15-network-and-downsize-fleet?utm_source=feed&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_content=main&amp;utm_campaign=rss,11/9/2012 23:40,MercoPress,Mainstream,General,Uruguay,company:IBERIA LINEAS AEREAS DE ESPANA SA|employees_number:one|fragment_count:1|status:announced
```

Downloadable CSV file [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19509627/SampleDataClean.csv)

For instance, output all the column headings, and row data etc to a table displayed on the HTML

Most of the research online seems to focus on incoming csv data similar to JSON data. But I cannot quite seem to find one that parses a CSV file. Any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: why not pass it to a back end application?

Comment: What language are you using on the server to receive the CSV file? Without knowing that, we can't help you.

Comment: i'm thinking of using server-side javascript

Comment: perhaps nodeJS could be a good way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually CSV files contains cells divided by a separator, like `;`: in your example the separator is `,`. So what you need to do is:

1) Read your CSV file into a `String`, for example you can name it `input`;

2) Create a String Array like this `String[] result = input.split("\\,");`;

3) Iterate your `result` as you wish.