# Python csv.reader() to JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I have a python code such as :

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('myText.txt', 'r'), delimiter=",")
for row in reader:
print row[0] + 'is' + row[1] + '</br>'
```

I look for a similar action/code[1] **in JS or JQuery**. The name of this action is welcome too. I'am exploring JS and wondering if there is a way do get an online/offline csv, parse it, iterate, inject some HTML in my website accordingly.

[1]: more precisely I look for a JS translation of **reader = csv.reader(open('myText.txt', 'r'), delimiter=",")** , I can manage the rest.

**Note:** myText.txt will be [this online file](https://raw.github.com/cburgmer/cjklib/master/cjklib/data/pinyinipamapping.csv)

Comment: Parsing the text is simple enough in javascript, but opening the file may be an issue.  You're aware that javascript runs client-side?  Or will the file be accessible via a url?

Comment: I'am aware JS run client side. I'am exploring JS and wondering if there is a way do get an online/offline csv, parse it, iterate, inject some HTML in my website accordingly.

Comment: You can't open a local file with JS, due to obvious security reasons.  If it's available via a url then you can do what you need (assuming it's on the same domain as the site).

Comment: You mean "external file" ?
Ok, so the target csv need to be on the same website. I can copy it on my website, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick and simple file it could be something like this: (Code inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431565/541842))

```
 // Put here the url to the file
 url = "https://raw.github.com/cburgmer/cjklib/master/cjklib/data/pinyinipamapping.csv";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
     });


function processData(allText) {
    // Get an array of lines
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    // Get the number of columns using the first row
    var entries = allTextLines[0].split(',');
    var lines = [];

    // while there are elements in the row
    while (entries.length>0) {
        // remove that line, split it and store in our array 
        lines.push(entries.shift().split(','));
    }
    // Now do your stuff with the array lines

}
```

Comment: From @Archer's comments, I understand that this code will work ONLY if bot my script and csv are on the same domain, right ?

Comment: I don't think it is that easy. [CORS Rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) are a little more complex. The hosting server would need to support it explicitly.

Comment: Also, it is more nitpicking, but you should mention in your answer that this is not complete [weapon grade CSV parsing](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). For example, it will not ignore the comment lines (which start with '#') in the original csv file.

Answer (score 2):

For the given CSV file, I think something like this should suffice (which uses only `jquery`):

```js
$.get('/path/to/pinyinipamapping.csv')
.done(function(csvData) {
    var body = $('body');
    csvData.split(/\r\n|\n/).forEach(function (rowStr) {
        if (rowStr[0] != '#') {
            var row = rowStr.split(',');
            body.append('<p>' + row[0] + 'is' + row[1] + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

However, this will not work for quoted commas, etc.

For a more complete CSV parsing look at [Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data) which uses code from [this blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm). Also, you can consider the [jQuery-csv library](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/), though it is in beta.

Comment: I +1ed your answer but validated @Fabio's answer in 2 parts, 2 parts may be easier to adapt to various contexts. But I will use parts of your code too. Thanks & +1 !

Comment: Be careful, his answer does not ignore comments in CSV which start with '#'.