# Read CSV from link with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, csv

is the best way to catch up CSV with ajax? 
such as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/api/myapilink/',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Hello' + data);
        }
    });
});
```

The received data from the CSV http link is:

```
"objectno";"objectname";"objectclassname";"objecttype";"description";
"lastmsgid";"deleted"
"026";"Demo 1";"Car";"";"";"107711249";"0"
"027";"Demo 2";"Car";"";"";"105985957";"0"
"028";"Demo 3";"Car";"";"";"107794499";"0"
```

I hope someone has an example or know!
(updated)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript

Comment: You're missing a quote at the end of the URL.

Comment: The get url part is not working (in the example from -Satpal.. my url likes : https://csv.csv_company.com?user=username&password=pass (etc)..

Comment: You could use `JSON` instead? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ I assume you have control over the output from `/api/myapilink`

Comment: Yep, but how do I get a right script with this?

Comment: can not find a solution .. the csv data is from a cross Damain and 
and headers, this has to be solved?