# how to make 2d array in JavaScript from csv structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

The structure will look like followings:

```
REP name,ID,Doctor name,speciality,Hospital,city
Abd A,3-1KPLCI,ASHWA,DERMATOLOGIST,ZULEKHA,SHARJAH
Abd A,3-1MSZMC,VINOD,INTERNIST,ZULEKHA,SHARJAH
Abd A,3-2MTAJU,ALI N,EMERGENCY,AL GARHO,NONE
Abd A,3-2S1WOT,ABDUL,GENERAL PRACTITIONER,CITY HOS,BUR DUBAI
```

I wanted to get 2D array. Like this

```
[
["Abd A","3-1KPLCI","ASHWA","DERMATOLOGIST"],
["Abd A","3-1MSZMC","VINOD","INTERNIST"],
[...................]
]
```

How can be done with JavaScript?

Update:
Actually I do not read csv file. I will copy csv data manually in the script. But JavaScript will create 2D array so that I can perform next process.

Comment: Check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data

Comment: possible duplicate of [How read data From \*.CSV file using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript)

Comment: I have figured out. Thanks