# d3.csv map column values as keys in object

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

[D3 Drag Drop Example](http://bl.ocks.org/thudfactor/6611441)

I am working through the Drag Drop Example an would like to read in data from a csv.

I would like to reformat the returned data from my csv file into a needed format. 
In a drag and drop scenario, the dragged element has a value from Array[3] and is dropped on an element with r1val(n). When those values match an event occurs.
I would like to find a way to set the values of the first column as key as  shown in the Object below.

file.csv:

```
  col1,col2,col3,col4
  r1val1,r1val2,r1val3,r1val4
  r2val1,r2val2,r2val3,r2val4
  ....
```

needed format:

```
  var colSet = {
  r1val1 : ["r1val2","r1val3","r1val4"],
  r2val1 : ["r2val2","r2val2","r2val2"],
  ...
  }
```

console.log of needed format:

```
Object
  r1val1: Array[3]
  r2val1: Array[3]
  ...
__proto__: Object
```

My target is this function:

```
var DragDropManager = {
    dragged: null,
    droppable: null,
    draggedMatchesTarget: function() {
        if (!this.droppable) return false;
        return (colSet[this.droppable].indexOf(this.dragged) >= 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762822/javascript-loading-csv-file-into-an-array You can parse with jquery but that might not be best.

Comment: @DotDotBeep - I have included the function where the object is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generates a [d3.map](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_map) instead of a JavaScript object, but should work for your situation (you can still access elements like an object with obj[key]):

```
d3.csv('test.csv',function(error,rows){

    var obj = d3.map(rows, function(d){
      return d.col1;
    });
    obj.forEach(function(k,v){
      this[k] = [v.col2, v.col3, v.col4];
    });

    console.log(obj);
  });
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6jbokmuafW1fGYBuYlGM?p=preview).

At this point, we are both overthinking it, how about:

```
d3.csv('test.csv', function(error, rows) {
  var obj = {};
  rows.forEach(function(d){
    obj[d.col1] = [d.col2, d.col3, d.col4];
  });
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Updated [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6jbokmuafW1fGYBuYlGM?p=preview).

Comment: Mark I have used d3.map, so far it did not work, I will try again.  The function in my 'UPDATE' does create the correct format, but once per row. I have a merge function for objects that works, now I have to figure out how to use it with a loop.

Comment: @EdDie, see new answer.  We are both getting too fancy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
d3.csv("data/language.csv", function(error, data) {


//reformatting data array content stripping 'key' and 'value'


var refData = data.map(function(d){ 
var rObj = {};
rObj[d.col1] = d.col3;
return rObj;
});


// function that merges Objects
function merge(target, source) {      
    /* Merges two (or more) objects,
   giving the last one precedence */   
if ( typeof target !== 'object' ) {
    target = {};
}   
for (var property in source) {      
    if ( source.hasOwnProperty(property) ) {          
        var sourceProperty = source[ property ];         
        if ( typeof sourceProperty === 'object' ) {
            target[ property ] = util.merge( target[ property ],    sourceProperty );
            continue;
        }        
        target[ property ] = sourceProperty;          
    }     
}    
for (var a = 2, l = arguments.length; a < l; a++) {
    merge(target, arguments[a]);
}   
return target;
};


//loops through the refData creating dwarfSet
for (i = 0; i < refData.length; i++) {
var dwarfSet = merge(refData[0],refData[i]);
};
```

This code actually produces the desired Object. I am not entirely happy with the loop function as it produces one dwarfSet per row, and not one overall.

Suggestions for improvement are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done simply with:

```
var obj = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.r1val1; })
  .entries(data);
```

http://learnjsdata.com/group_data.html