# Javascript, parsing a CSV file

Tags: javascript, regex, csv, unicode, utf-8

Problem: Parsing a CSV file client side with Javascript.

First question is what kind of encoding is this ? The following is the result of executing the command:

```
cat file.csv | xxd
```

The file is not complete here, you only see the header line and the beginning of the second line.

```
0000000: 4500 2d00 6d00 6100 6900 6c00 2000 6100  E.-.m.a.i.l. .a.
0000010: 6400 7200 6500 7300 3b00 5200 6f00 6500  d.r.e.s.;.R.o.e.
0000020: 7000 6e00 6100 6100 6d00 3b00 4100 6300  p.n.a.a.m.;.A.c.
0000030: 6800 7400 6500 7200 6e00 6100 6100 6d00  h.t.e.r.n.a.a.m.
0000040: 3b00 4300 7200 6500 6400 6900 7400 6500  ;.C.r.e.d.i.t.e.
0000050: 7500 7200 6e00 7500 6d00 6d00 6500 7200  u.r.n.u.m.m.e.r.
0000060: 3b00 4700 6f00 6500 6400 6b00 6500 7500  ;.G.o.e.d.k.e.u.
0000070: 7200 6400 6500 7200 7300 3b00 4600 7500  r.d.e.r.s.;.F.u.
0000080: 6e00 6300 7400 6900 6500 3b00 4b00 6f00  n.c.t.i.e.;.K.o.
0000090: 7300 7400 6500 6e00 7000 6c00 6100 6100  s.t.e.n.p.l.a.a.
00000a0: 7400 7300 3b00 4200 6500 6800 6500 6500  t.s.;.B.e.h.e.e.
00000b0: 7200 6400 6500 7200 3b00 4400 6500 6300  r.d.e.r.;.D.e.c.
00000c0: 6c00 6100 7200 6100 6e00 7400 3b00 4700  l.a.r.a.n.t.;.G.
00000d0: 6f00 6500 6400 6b00 6500 7500 7200 6400  o.e.d.k.e.u.r.d.
00000e0: 6500 7200 3b00 4500 7800 7000 6f00 7200  e.r.;.E.x.p.o.r.
00000f0: 7400 6500 7500 7200 3b00 4700 6500 6100  t.e.u.r.;.G.e.a.
0000100: 6300 7400 6900 7600 6500 6500 7200 6400  c.t.i.v.e.e.r.d.
0000110: 3b00 5000 6500 7200 7300 6f00 6e00 6500  ;.P.e.r.s.o.n.e.
0000120: 6500 6c00 7300 6e00 7500 6d00 6d00 6500  e.l.s.n.u.m.m.e.
0000130: 7200 3b00 4700 6500 6200 7200 7500 6900  r.;.G.e.b.r.u.i.
0000140: 6b00 6500 7200 7300 6e00 6100 6100 6d00  k.e.r.s.n.a.a.m.
0000150: 3b00 5500 3300 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000  ;.U.3. . . . . .
0000160: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
0000170: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
0000180: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
0000190: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
00001a0: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
00001b0: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
00001c0: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
00001d0: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
00001e0: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
00001f0: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 0d00   . . . . . . ...
0000200: 0a00 4100 2e00 4a00 4100 4e00 5300 4500  ..A...J.A.N.S.E.
```

To parse the file we want to be able to loop over each line. To do that we use the following regex:

```
lines = str.match(/[^\r\n]+/g)
```

The result looks like that:

```
['...\u0000', '\u0000', '\u0000...']
```

But it should actually look like that:

```
['... ', 'A...']
```

If the file is not the problem, what regex can I use to not have the null bytes "breaking" the regex.

Edit:

- Executing `file -I` returns `application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

Comment: I think that this is a misuse of the xxd commad. From a quick google search the xxd command creates a hex dump of the file which defeats the purpose of formatting it as a csv. Try running it through your parser without using xxd.

Comment: I just used the comment so that you can see the exact content of the file, the file.

Comment: The encoding is probably UTF-16 (Little Endian) or UCS-2.

Comment: You need to read the file with a UTF-16LE decoder. What's your environment, are we talking about a Node app? BTW, the above regex isn't suitable for splitting lines in a CSV file, as it would match newlines in quoted fields.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to write this mechanism yourself?
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23763523) answer to a similar question, which references a jQuery-plugin for reading csv-files.
(Not enough rep to comment, so there goes my answer)

Also, since the encoding seems to be 16 bits wide, I don't think regex is the best approach to this. Even if it was only 8 bits, dealing with binary formats is usually really really difficult, unless you know exactly, what every byte of the input is meaning.