# d3 rollup on each csv columns

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use d3.rollup to get the summation of each column.
`data.csv` looks like this:

```
DateTime, A, B, C
2020/2/27 7:16  3   0   1
2020/2/26 23:44 1   0   4
2020/2/26 21:35 1   1   0
2020/2/26 15:14 1   0   3
2020/2/25 20:35 1   1   0
2020/2/25 16:10 1   0   3
```

**Desired output:**

```
2020/2/27   3   0   1
2020/2/26   3   1   7
2020/2/25   2   1   3
```

I would like to group my data on a daily basis. I am trying to nest the data using `d3.nest` but failing to map the data on each column.

I do not want to call out the columns by name such as `d3.sum(d.A)`. Instead, I want to map the data to all columns.

```
var nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function(c) {return parseDate(new Date(c.datetime)); })//parseDate
```

To get date by month:

```
.rollup(function(d){return {
  values: d3.sum(d.map(function(v) {
  return +v[d];}))};})
.entries(data);
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've just started with js and d3.

Comment: I've not used ``d3.rollup()`` but here is a good article: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-group. I'll read it and if nobody has answered here yet, I'll try to give it a go.

Comment: thanks! I have looked it up already without any luck

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an answer with vanilla js and I'll try to come back and give a d3 answer once I've read enough of the docs.

You can do it like this:

csv:

```
DateTime, A, B, C
2020/2/27 7:16,  3,   0,   1
2020/2/26 23:44, 1,   0,   4
2020/2/26 21:35, 1,   1,   0
2020/2/26 15:14, 1,   0,   3
2020/2/25 20:35, 1,   1,   0
2020/2/25 16:10, 1,   0,   3
```

Which we could convert to a JSON / JavaScript array many ways, such as:

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61080978/9792594:

```js
const csv2json = (str, delimiter = ',') => {
  const titles = str.slice(0, str.indexOf('\n')).split(delimiter);
  const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf('\n') + 1).split('\n');
  return rows.map(row => {
    const values = row.split(delimiter);
    return titles.reduce((object, curr, i) => (object[curr.trim()] = values[i].trim(), object), {})
  });
};


let csv =
`DateTime, A, B, C
2020/2/27 7:16,  3,   0,   1
2020/2/26 23:44, 1,   0,   4
2020/2/26 21:35, 1,   1,   0
2020/2/26 15:14, 1,   0,   3
2020/2/25 20:35, 1,   1,   0
2020/2/25 16:10, 1,   0,   3`;

let word_array = csv2json(csv,',');
console.log(word_array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

JSON / JavaScript Array:

```js
[
  {
    "DateTime": "2020/2/27 7:16",
    "A": 3,
    "B": 0,
    "C": 1
  },
  {
    "DateTime": "2020/2/26 23:44",
    "A": 1,
    "B": 0,
    "C": 4
  },
  {
    "DateTime": "2020/2/26 21:35",
    "A": 1,
    "B": 1,
    "C": 0
  },
  {
    "DateTime": "2020/2/26 15:14",
    "A": 1,
    "B": 0,
    "C": 3
  },
  {
    "DateTime": "2020/2/25 20:35",
    "A": 1,
    "B": 1,
    "C": 0
  },
  {
    "DateTime": "2020/2/25 16:10",
    "A": 1,
    "B": 0,
    "C": 3
  }
]
```

Answer to your question (aggregate data based on date):

- use reduce, to create an object with each day as a key (parse date)
- when the key already exists, merge the values on A, B, C
- convert Object to an array with `Object.values`

```js
const myData = [{"DateTime":"2020/2/27 7:16","A":3,"B":0,"C":1},{"DateTime":"2020/2/26 23:44","A":1,"B":0,"C":4},{"DateTime":"2020/2/26 21:35","A":1,"B":1,"C":0},{"DateTime":"2020/2/26 15:14","A":1,"B":0,"C":3},{"DateTime":"2020/2/25 20:35","A":1,"B":1,"C":0},{"DateTime":"2020/2/25 16:10","A":1,"B":0,"C":3}];

const groupedData = Object.values(myData.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
  
  const dateOnly = new Date(item.DateTime).toLocaleDateString();
  
  if (aggObj.hasOwnProperty(dateOnly)){
    Object.entries(aggObj[dateOnly]).forEach(([key,val]) => {
      if (key != 'DateTime'){
        aggObj[dateOnly][key] = val + item[key];
      }
    });
  } else {
    aggObj[dateOnly] = {...item, "DateTime": dateOnly};
  }
  
  return aggObj;
  
}, {}));

console.log(groupedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: great! I will wait for your take on D3 way. Thanks!