# How to convert a .csv file into an array/matrix in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I have a table in a .csv file format, which I need to use in my program. What I need to do is read the file, and then convert it into a two dimensional array/matrix.

I found this code below, which reads a .csv file and converts it into a string, but I don't know how to access the string, and furthermore convert it into an array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="file" id="csvFile" accept=".csv" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <script>

        const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
        const csvFile = document.getElementById("csvFile");
        myForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const input = csvFile.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                const text = e.target.result;
                document.write(text);
            };
            reader.readAsText(input);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried saving the string into a variable, but I keep encoutering errors, like '"text" is not defined' etc. I am very new to JavaScript so please bear with me :)

Comment: and [Javascript loading CSV file into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762822/javascript-loading-csv-file-into-an-array) and the 13 year old duplicate [How to parse CSV data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/how-to-parse-csv-data)

Comment: I have an answer for the first half. The other half...probably uses `.split`? I've never really used CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for the first half.

When you use `FileReader.prototype.readAsText`, you have to wait for it to finish. You can use the `loadend` event to check for this. Then, the `FileReader`'s `result` property will contain the string.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader