# html Roster page for sports team (inc. importing player data by csv)

Tags: html, csv

I'm rewriting the site linked [here](http://www.durhamsaints.co.uk/squad.html) and want to try find a better way of entering/storing the player data.

It's currently a tabbed panel setup (ignore the poor formatting/layout, that's being fixed already) with a table as each content, manually written every time a new player is added. This is a lot of code, messy, and hard for someone else to edit.

What I'd ideally like to end up with is one (or a set of) csv file(s) stored on the server which when edited, will automatically update the html page.

I've looked at a few examples but found nothing so far that strikes me as perfect - the final site will ideally alphabetise all the entries and include a photo as it already does (the photos can be stored by name which will match the name in the players data). Essentially it displays as it does already but with the data stored more sensibly.

If anyone can suggest a good way of attempting this it would be much appreciated; I'm afraid I have only a very basic knowledge of java and pretty much no php (but then not even sure if it's installed on the server!) but I'm fairly comfortable in html and css

Comment: The question is: why are you not using a DB ?

Comment: Look into [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) and add a JSON file with the values. Then you can sort with jQuery. I built something similar in function for selecting videos. Check out this repo and the demo site. [https://github.com/GLJuan/video-player](https://github.com/GLJuan/video-player)

Answer (score 0):

My spontaneous answer is that it will be hard to achieve without involving any form of server side language (php, .net, python etc), that would probably be the most elegant way of going about what you're trying to do. However you COULD use jQuery and read the entire CSV and then create the page as required using Javascript. But that would be quite a long way around a fairly simple problem.

Check out this thread for information regarding how to read CSV using jquery
[How to read data From *.CSV file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript)