# html onclick for dictionary mode implementation

Tags: php, html

Html newbie here..

I am trying to implement a webpage that pops up meanings of some selected technical words as shown below. I have a list of words with their meanings available in csv format. What can be done to automatically pick meanings for available list of words from the list?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {

}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2></h2>
<p>Hands-On with <div class="dropdown">
<button id="myBtn" class="dropbtn">Ultrahaptics'</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Feel of touch without wearing devices</a>

  </div>
</div>
 gave us a feel of technology of future.
</p>

<script>
// Get the button, and when the user clicks on it, execute myFunction
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

/* myFunction toggles between adding and removing the show class, which is used to hide and show the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PS:Things like

```
<a title="Feel of touch without wearing devices">Ultrahaptics'</a>
```

works only with mouse pointers, not with touch device. So looking for a solution that works on touch devices too.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your using javascript. I would recommend using [jQuery-CSV](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/)

this would help you read your csv using javascript. And you can visit this link as this is somewhat related to your question. [Evans Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript/12289296#12289296)

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery, this would be a simple case of:

```
$('.dropbtn').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

With the following CSS:

```
.dropdown-content{
  position:absolute;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

And I've simplified your HTML:

```
<p>
  Hands-On with
  <span class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="dropbtn">Ultrahaptics'</button>
    <a href="#home" class="dropdown-content hide">Feel of touch without wearing devices</a>
  </span>
  gave us a feel of technology of future.
</p>
```

You can see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/a73t8L4m/

You may also be interested in using [the `dfn` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dfn.asp), but this would make your HTML look a little different.

Comment: Even in this case, I have to manually update every occurance of technical words. There are 1000s of such occurances. I'm looking to automatically search technical words and show their meanings from csv file.Not necessarily a dynamic solution, even a static solution would be fine. I can run the update whenever there is update in csv file or article.

Comment: @niko The easiest thing to do would be to use a database like MySQL to store your data, and a language like PHP to display it.

Comment: @niko also, your question started by mentioning CSS. What you are asking for has nothing to do with CSS.