# How To Convert CSV file to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, csv

i have csv file with the content :
heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4,heading5
value1_1,value2_1,value3_1,value4_1,value5_1
value1_2,value2_2,value3_2,value4_2,value5_2

I create Javascript/HTML code to pick up that file and display the content

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>show csv</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple />
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
        //Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
        var files = evt.target.files; 

        if (files) {
            for (var i=0, f; f=files[i]; i++) {
                  var r = new FileReader();
                r.onload = (function(f) {
                    return function(e) {
                        var contents = e.target.result;
                        var res = document.getElementById("result");
                        res.innerHTML = "Got the file<br>" 
                              +"name: " + f.name + "<br>"
                              +"type: " + f.type + "<br>"
                              +"size: " + f.size + " bytes</br>"
                              + "starts with: " + contents; 
                    };
                })(f);

                r.readAsText(f);
            }   
        } else {
              alert("Failed to load files"); 
        }
      }

          document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change',readMultipleFiles, false);
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

and the output is like :
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZozmT.png)

question : How can i convert the content or the data to array and showing as html table ?

thanks for any help.

Comment: you showed us your code, but what is the problem? please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: All you need to do to get the values into an array is: `var ary = values.split(",");` From there, you can loop the values and do whatever you want.

Comment: Please note a key phrase in the link provided by @PhilippSander: "Search... and research", because this question answers a good chunk of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7431268/215552

Answer (score 1):

You can convert csv data into array and then into html table. I have added \n into your new line. Please add the \n to your code when there is a new line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style>
         table {
         border-collapse: collapse;
         border: 2px black solid;
         font: 12px sans-serif;
         }
         td {
         border: 1px black solid;
         padding: 5px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id='container'></div>
      <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
         var data = 'heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4,heading5\nvalue1_1,value2_1,value3_1,value4_1,value5_1\nvalue1_2,value2_2,value3_2,value4_2,value5_2';
         var lines = data.split("\n"),
         output = [],
         i;
         for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
         output.push("<tr><td>"
         + lines[i].slice(0,-1).split(",").join("</td><td>")
         + "</td></tr>");
         output = "<table>" + output.join("") + "</table>";
         var div = document.getElementById('container');
         
         div.innerHTML = output;
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Kapila Perera's answer to be very useful. However, the last element of each row was being cropped due to the `slice(0,-1)` use. Building on Perera's answer, in the example below I've used `slice()` instead.

I've also separated out the first row `lines[0]` as a header row and loop from 1 instead (which won't always be the case that csv contains headers but is explicitly called out in the example).

Finally, I've added the `tbody` tags when the output gets wrapped but this probably isn't required.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
        var div = document.getElementById('container');
        var data = 'heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4,heading5\nvalue1_1,value2_1,value3_1,value4_1,value5_1\nvalue1_2,value2_2,value3_2,value4_2,value5_2';
        var lines = data.split("\n"), output = [], i;

        /* HEADERS */
        output.push("<tr><th>" 
            + lines[0].slice().split(",").join("</th><th>") 
            + "</th></tr>");

        for (i = 1; i < lines.length; i++)
            output.push("<tr><td>" 
                + lines[i].slice().split(",").join("</td><td>") 
                + "</td></tr>");

        output = "<table><tbody>" 
                    + output.join("") + "</tbody></table>";

        div.innerHTML = output;
    </script>
```