# Plot a Line chart using Chart.js with CSV Data

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I need to plot a simple line chart using the chart.js library from CSV data, which is in the following format:

data.csv

```
"year","rate"
1952-53,3.00%
1953-54,3.00%
1954-55,3.50%
.......
```

I want year to be on the x-axis and rate to be on the y-axis. I need to do completely using chart.js. Can anyone help me in doing this?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I have tried plotting line chart using chart.js.But not able to plot x and y-axis

Comment: sharing your code would help us to help you

Comment: [Parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript), then use chart.js as normal or use a [plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489790/how-do-i-import-a-csv-into-chart-js).

Answer (score 0):

Chartjs doesn't support direct CSV files. So you have to convert it to JSON-like format. What you can do is create a server side script in php/nodejs that will convert csv to json on the go. Then give that data to chartjs

```
$file="1_23.csv";
$csv= file_get_contents($file);
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
$json = json_encode($array);
print_r($json);
```

Comment: I have converted csv to json ,but still it not happening

Comment: also chartjs is not that good for dates. Try canvasjs http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/date-time-axis/

Comment: I have converted csv to json ,but still it not happening    below is json format:   [{"FIELD1":"YEAR", "FIELD2":"RATE"},{"FIELD1":"1952-53", "FIELD2":"3.00%"},{"FIELD1":"1953-54", "FIELD2":"3.00%"}]

Comment: Your format is not right. In the rate field. It must be integer/float. Your rate contains "%" symbol. Remove that. Also in the year field, what is "-53"?

Comment: There's no need to go to the server for this. There are plenty of ways to do this completely in-memory in the front end. See [How to read data From *.CSV file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use `csv()` from the [D3.js library](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#csvParse)

Lets say you have that data in a `data.csv` that looks something like this:

```
"year","rate"
1952-53,3.00
1953-54,3.00
1954-55,3.50
```

First create a function to map the CSV column data to an array:

```
function makeChart(sampledata) {
 var sampledataLabels = sampledata.map(function(d) {
       return d.year;
         });
  var weeksData = sampledata.map(function(d) {
        return +d.rate;
          });

  var chart = new Chart('chart', {
        type: "line",
            data: {
              labels: sampledataLabels,
              datasets: [
                  {
                      data: weeksData
                  }
                ]
              }
          });
}
```

Then read it in via `d3.csv()`

```
d3.csv('so_chart.csv')
  .then(makeChart);
```

I got most of this code from this excellent [blog post from createwithdata.com](http://%20https://www.createwithdata.com/chartjs-and-csv/)

Comment: d3 seems like overkill just for CSV conversion. A dedicated CSV parsing library could do it in a fraction of the size of d3, such as [Papa Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126869/6243352).