# How to use chart.js for financial with dynamic CSV data?

Tags: chart.js

I was looking for a small footprint chart library and stumbled upon chart.js. I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel, and am looking for some example code on how to import data from a CSV file using chart.js?

Also, does it matter whether I use my data file in JSON format versus CSV file? Are there any advantages to either one?

Here is my CSV code :

```
time,price1,price2,price3
2020:05:19 22:07:48,300,167,290
2020:05:20 22:07:48,320,200,190
2020:05:21 22:07:48,130,169,210
2020:05:22 22:07:48,178,199,290
2020:05:23 22:07:48,245,198,200
2020:05:24 22:07:48,378,168,280
```

Comment: were you able to get it done ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import a csv into chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489790/how-do-i-import-a-csv-into-chart-js)

Answer (score 0):

for csv data you could use file as var, use d3.csv and map data to time and values.