# How to output data from a .csv in an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `.csv` file that is being saved from a MySQL Query on a Raspberry Pi, and I would like to simply output the sum of `column_1` in an HTML output.

I would just like to output a sentence like, *The sum of column_1 is: XXX*, but I am unsure how to access the .csv file in my directory, find the sum of a specific column, and then output that sum.

Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Comment: this involves back-end programming like php. not just HTML.  Have you tried using any programming language?

Comment: I'm familiar with Python and scripting based languages.  I wonder if there is some interface between Python data cleansing to an HTML output?

Comment: So I think the title question should be convert csv file to HTML using python of something like that. But for csv I think you can simply parse the data out. You can always refer to the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Please r&d on How to read .csv file using javascript in google OR refer stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript) then you will sure about how to give output in .html page from .csv file.