# Highcharts Guage Series from CSV

Tags: csv, charts, highcharts, jsfiddle, gauge

I am creating a gauge chart with (2) needles, separate values. I need them to update everyday from an external csv file. I have the working chart at: http://fiddle.jshell.net/U95uE/23/ but cannot successfully duplicate this when trying to load data from an external csv file. The csv file would only contain (1) row and (2) columns, ex: -1000000000, 2000000000. Could anyone fiddle a solution to this? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Read how to load csv file [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript). After you fetch the csv file, you need to parse it - example [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/U95uE/25/)

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you for your help. Although when I moved this to the test environment I cannot get the external .csv file to load. It only seems to work by getting the data from the Id. Any thoughts? I read through the link and tried a few of the ways listed with no success. Thanks again.

Comment: "I cannot get the external .csv file to load" can mean a lot of things. What platform are you working on? What precisely do you mean when you say you can't get it to load? Where does it fail? What error messages are you receiving (if none, what error reporting is turned on?)? Etc.

Comment: Working great now. Thank you everyone for your help!