# Reading CSV file to binary format, getting console error

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read a CSV file as binary format to send to an API.

I use the following HTML input - file

```
<input type="file" name=filedata (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />

fileChangeEvent(e)
{
  var fileData, file = e.target.files[0], reader = new FileReader();
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }
  reader.onload = function(e) {
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

But, I am getting the following error

> ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'readAsBinaryString'

Comment: see [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) - firstly, `readAsBinaryString` is deprecated, and secondly, never supported in Internet Exploder - which browser are you attempting this with

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data From \*.CSV file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript)

Comment: I am using IE @Jaromanda X

Comment: I want to convert file data to binary format, not duplicate question @Liam

Comment: I tried your documentation @Jaromanda X, not able to resolve issue

Comment: did you read my first comment? IE does not and never has supported the now deprecated `readAsBinaryString` - the suggested alternative is `readAsArrayBuffer` - but that is only supported in IE10+ - typically, you just say you are using "IE" ... should I gaze into my crystal ball to discover which version of that most hated steam powered browser you are vainly hanging on to for god knows what reason?

Comment: I am using IE 11, I tried with readAsArrayBuffer, coming empty array with no data. I tried in chrome too. Same issue exists @Jaromanda X

Comment: Does Internet Exploder handle this -> https://jsfiddle.net/pk3L7kh6/

Comment: `Same issue exists` - if the same issue exists, then you're still trying to use `readAsBinaryString` rather than `readAsArrayBuffer`