# How to get CSV file behind Java object for LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: javascript, php, sql, mysqli

I want to access a CSV file behind a Javascript object for my LOAD DATA INFILE function.

e.g. the "Download Max" button on this page,
https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/Znh18/price-history/historical
OR 
The "Download a Spreadsheet" button on this page,
http://quotes.wsj.com/bond/BX/TMUBMUSD10Y/historical-prices#

This is my code

```
...
$csvfile = '\'/home4/cascaderange/public_html/00_test/znh18_180208.csv\'';
$cminfile = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '
            .$csvfile.' 
            replace INTO TABLE TABLE04 FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\' 
            IGNORE 1 LINES;';

mysqli_query($conn,$cminfile) or die(mysqli_error());
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please say what the actual problem your having is.

Comment: Sorry. the LOAD DATA INFILE function needs a file, $csvfile above. To get another CSV file I just change the link, e.g.  'http://mooremarkettrends.com/00_test/znh18_180208.csv'. However, the files at barchart.com and wsj.com, above, do not have direct links because the user must click a JS button. So, how do I write the link to get the file from barchart.com or wsj.com? thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **openCSV library** for this. I did'nt use before .
 [Try this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript)