# How to load csv file into variable for usage with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to write all values from a specific column in a `.csv` file to an array.
Please execute the following working example and notice, that all the values from the column `Address` are successfully written into the array variable `tmpArr`

```js
var csvString= "Address,longitude,latitude,geometry\n"+
"1,2,3,4\n5,6,7,8\n2,3,4,5\n6,7,8,9";

var t = d3.csv.parse(csvString);
var tmpArr = t.map(function(d){return d.Address;});
console.log(tmpArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

But how can I load a `.csv` file into the variable `csvString` instead of a hardcoded string?

I successfully load the `.csv` file via ajax, but I only get the output `,,,`

```
csvToChart("daten/kundenimporte/", "test.csv");

function csvToChart(basepath, filename)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: basepath + filename,
        method: "GET",
        success: myCallback
    });
}

function myCallback(response)
{
    var t = d3.csv.parse(response);
    d3.select("#output").html(
        t.map(function(d){
            return d.Kundengruppe;
        })
    );
}
```

I get `ReferenceError: d is not defined`.

How can I successfully load my `.csv` file?

Comment: Why use jQuery at all? [`d3.csv()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#csv) will do both, the loading **and** the parsing: `d3.csv("daten/kundenimporte/test.csv", myCallback);`. In `myCallback()` just use `response` which contains the parsed CSV as an array of objects already, no need for `t`.

Comment: Im not sure how exactly to use your solution. It would be very nice if you could help me out

Comment: Ok, I'll put that into an answer. Are you bound to using D3 **v3** or could you opt for *v5*?

Comment: Im not bound to a specific version @altocumulus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to mix in jQuery as D3 provides methods for conveniently loading **and** parsing CSV files.

In the old versions 3 or 4 of D3 you could use [`d3.csv()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md#csv) which was part of the now deprecated [d3-request](https://github.com/d3/d3-request) module. This will employ an Ajax request for loading the file's content:

```
d3.csv("daten/kundenimporte/test.csv", function(data) {
  d3.select("#output").html(
    data.map(function(d){
      return d.Address;
    })
  );
});
```

If you decide on upgrading to v5, however, things have slightly [changed](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50), since [`d3.csv()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#csv) despite having the same name is now part of the [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) module and will return a Promise instead of executing a callback. Your code then becomes:

```
d3.csv("daten/kundenimporte/test.csv")
  .then(function(data) {   // Handle the resolved Promise
    d3.select("#output").html(
      data.map(function(d){
        return d.Address;
      })
    );
  });
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but the parameter `data` seems to be unused? I also get `ReferenceError: t is not defined` on your first example.

Comment: @Black My bad, of course it needs to be `data` instead of the `t` I copied over from your code. See the update.

Comment: You don't have a property `Kundengruppe` in your CSV, hence, it logs `undefined`, try `Address` instead.

Comment: Ohh man Im so sorry, It was only because I accidentially used `Kundengruppe` instead of `Address`... now it works!Thx!

Comment: My company uses `;` in .csv files for whatever reason, can someone please tell me how to deal with this? I replaced `d3.csv` with `d3.dsv` but It does not work. My only idea is to read the .csv file and replace the chars with javascript then load it with `d3.csv`

Comment: Yes I tried it, it did not worked. But I finally solved it like this `d3.dsv(';')("daten/kundenimporte/test.csv", function(data) { ... }`

Answer (score -2):

If you dont mind using a jQuery library, here might be an answer for you problem:
[How to read data From *.CSV file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript/12289296#12289296)

Otherwise a person added his own "quick and dirty" function above ^that answer.

Hope that helps.

/Good luck and happy coding

Answer (score -2):

You should now migrate to d3 V4/V5. In V4, it goes like below.

```
d3.csv("your_path_to_csv file", function(data) {
//Your code goes here

//Now you can use 'data' variable as an array of objects
console.log
});
```

In V5, It goes like

```
d3.csv("your_path_to_csv file").then(function(data) {
//Your code
});
```