# Parse CSV without download / saving

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, csv

I am creating an application that allows users to upload a CSV. The CSV is just a comma separated file.

On the frontend, I send the file to my backend with a PUT request:

**Reactjs** | fileupload_frontend.js

```
sendFile = () => {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', this.myCSV_file);

  axios.post('/parse-csv', data)
  .then(response => console.log('File sent to server for parsing')
  .catch(error => console.log(error);
}
```

The above code successfully sends the uploaded CSV (info) to my server, which is listening at the `/parse-csv` endpoint.

I am using the `csv-parser` npm package to help with this.

**Nodejs** | fileupload_backend.js

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs  = require('fs');
const results = [];

app.post('/parse-csv', (request, response) => {

  fs.createReadStream(request.files.file.data) { // this is a buffer on the req obj
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', results.push())
    .on('end', (results) => {
      console.log(results);
    }
  }

}
```

For reference, the request object from the frontend to the backend looks like:

```
Request from upload { name: 'data.csv',
data: <Buffer 22 89 56 24 5y 86 k9 22 . ... >,
encoding: '7bit',
truncated: false,
mimetype: 'text/csv',
md5: [Function: md5],
mv: [Function: mv] }
```

It is error-ing out on each request with a message that seems to be related to my header rows (first row in the csv file), with a message that reads:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'my,header,row,is,referenced,here'

...then the data is shown below.

Do I have to save the CSV file in some directory, then parse it first? I am just looking for a way to parse the CSV into json, so I can insert each row as an entry into my database.

Comment: What is the expected size of the csv? It may be easier to do it all in memory - no streams. Looking at the source of parse-csv - it seems overly complicated

Comment: @niry The file is 0.62kb

Comment: @bruh why dont you parse it on frontend?

Comment: @AbhishekMani would I do this using the same `csv-parser` package, except in my react code instead of node? Is there some native Javascript function to parse CSVs? Forgive me if I'm missing the obvious, I've been struggling with this for 10hours now, and just running out of steam

Comment: there is a module by which you can parse your CSV content at frontend easily,do let me know if you are stuck using that library

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815647/how-to-approach-parsing-csv-in-javascript/52817190#52817190

Comment: This is pretty tiny and doesn't need streaming... I like @AbhishekMani's idea. Here is a well tested code I wrote to parse CSV data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data/41563966#41563966

Comment: vote for it :) ;) @niry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[fs.createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) accepts a path as its argument which can be a string, Buffer or URL.

Since you pass a `Buffer`, it tries to open the `Buffer` as a path so it errors with

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'my,header,row,is,referenced,here'

You need to create a stream from the Buffer before piping it to the CSV parser.
There a various ways to go about this; implementing a Readable stream that uses the buffer is one. *e.g.*

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');

class BufferStream extends Readable {
  constructor(opts) {
    super(opts);
    this.buf = opts.buf;
  }
  _read(size) {
    this.push(this.buf);
    this.push(null); // signal end of stream
  }
}
```

Now implement the request handler to use this class.

```
app.post('/parse-csv', (request, response) => {
    const results = [];
    const bufStream = new BufferStream(request.files.file.data);

    bufStream.pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
    .on('end', (results) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
      response.sendStatus(200);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the following package, https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx. It will allow you to parse csv and most spreadsheet file formats interchangeably.

You can use it in the following way:

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx')
const workbook = XLSX.readFile(source_file_path)
const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0]
const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName]
const obj = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet)
```

This should work for any spread sheet format supported by the library.

This does mean that the file must be saved somewhere in your directory structure in for the `XLSX.readFile` to work.

Answer (score 3):

this is my solution, it works with buffer dirrectly and doesn't need to save file,
just install module "csv-parse" first.

```
 const { parse } = require('csv-parse/sync');

 const data = await parse(request.files.file.data);
```

and callback version

```
const csv = require('csv-parse');
   
csv.parse(request.files.file.data, function (err, data) {
           console.log('my_data', data);
         )}
```