# Stuck with the CSV file reading in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Hi I am trying to read the csv file (just on front end not want to store it on back end ). The error I am getting is attached with the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIhze.png)

The code I am trying is.

```
function file(){
       var fullPath = document.getElementById('upload').value;

       if (fullPath) {
            var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
            var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);

       if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
        filename = filename.substring(1);
       }

    alert(filename);
   // passFile(filename);
    d3.csv(filename, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;
           console.log(data); // [{"Hello": "world"}, …]
    });
  }
}
```

I just want to read the data from file but getting this error.
I have tried other ways too like [This method I tried first but does not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript). Can anyone help me out?

Comment: 500 is an error code return from server side, it indicate there is some error at your server side. You may want to check if [http://127.0.0.1:8000/aws/project_launch/view/helper.csv]  is accessible first.

Comment: No it is not accessible

Comment: What can I do for server side I do not know literally what is wrong on server side.

Comment: Can you add example of your csv?

Comment: Title, x, y , z
aaa, 2 ,2, 2
bbb, 1 ,1,1
ccc, 3, 3,3

Comment: @A.Meshu I have uploaded the example csv in above comment

Answer (score -1):

`d3.csv()` function is for fetching csv file from a remote location. If you want to read a local file by `<input type="file">` element, you should use `FileReader` to read the file by yourself and parse it with `d3.csvParse()` function.

**For example:**

```js
function file(){
 var uploadFileEl = document.getElementById('upload');
 
 if(uploadFileEl.files.length > 0){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
   console.log(d3.csvParse(reader.result));
  }
  reader.readAsText(uploadFileEl.files[0]);
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" />
<button id="upload" onclick="file()">Read CSV</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```