# Load CSV file data into HTML table

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load data from an csv file to an html file and I want to have it displayed in a table.

My idea was to open the csv data and split it with this code in table rows and and then the cells for the rows.

This is my code so far. Maybe you can help me with what's wrong?
I am thankful for any idea!

```
<body>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function readCsv(data) {
            var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
            var table = "<table>";
            for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows - length; singleRow++) {
                if (singleRow === 0) {
                    table += "<thead>";
                    table += "<tr>";
                } else {
                    table += "<tr>";
                }
                var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split(',');
                for (var rowCell = 0; rowCell < rowCells.length; rowCell++) {
                    if (singleRow === 0) {
                        table += "<th>";
                        table += rowCells[rowCell];
                        table += "</th>";
                    } else {
                        table += "<td>";
                        table += rowCells[rowCell];
                        table += "</td>";
                    }

                    if (singleRow === 0) {
                        table += "</tr>";
                        table += "</thead>";
                        table += "<tbody>";
                    } else {
                        table += "</tr>";
                    }
                }
                table += "</tbody>";
                table += "</table>";
                $("body").append(table);
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "world_data_v1.csv",
                dataType: "text"
            }).done(readCsv);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data From \*.CSV file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$.ajax` should be outside `readCsv` and inside a `$(document).(ready)`