# Convert String Array to Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, controller

What I am doing is I need to upload a .csv file and get the data inside, I check and use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript) but is return array of string i try to find a way to convert it but I can't find one

```
function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = ["Code", "LongName", "value", "dateFrom", "dateTo", "money"]

    var lines = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {

            var tarr = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                tarr.push(headers[j] + ":" + data[j]);
            }
            lines.push(tarr);
        }
    }

    console.log(lines);
    upload(lines);
}
```

Array of string(actual output):

```
0: Array()
    0: "Code:"'0000000001""
    1: "LongName:"TEST1""
    2: "value:0.0000"
    3: "dateFrom:"07-10-2019""
    4: "dateTo:"07-11-2019""
    5: "money:0.0000"
```

Expected Output:

```
0:
    code: "0000000001"
    longName: "TEST1"
    value: 0.0000
    dateFrom: "07-10-2019"
    dateTo: "07-11-2019"
    money: 0.0000
```

Comment: In `Array of string(actual output):` are 0,1,2 .... indexes of array or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using object and bracket notation

```js
function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.replace(/"/g, '').split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = ["Code", "LongName", "value", "dateFrom", "dateTo", "money"]

    var lines = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {

            var tarr = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                tarr[headers[j]] = data[j];
            }
            lines.push(tarr);
        }
    }
    console.log(lines);
    //upload(lines);
}

processData('\n\"0000000001\",Test"1,0.0000,07-10-2019,07-11-2019,0.0000')
```

Comment: I have updated my question sorry if i type a wrong output. I have tried your code but can this work with the updated output above? Thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is assign your array to an object with `Object.assign()`

```
function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = ["Code", "LongName", "value", "dateFrom", "dateTo", "money"]

    var lines = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {

            var tarr = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                tarr.push(headers[j] + ":" + data[j]);
            }
            lines.push(tarr);
        }
    }
let objectOfLines=Object.assign({},lines)
    console.log(lines,objectOfLines);
    upload(objectOfLines);
}
```

Comment: Hi sir. I have updated my question, please have a look at it. Thanks for helping.