# Extract image src attribute from thousands of links - Task automation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, automation, task

I have an excel file where there are around 2,000 URLs (divided in 4 columns).
If you go to a particular URL, you will find that there is a main image. I want to extract the `src=""` attribute from each URL so I can have the .JPG URL.

[Here is an example of one of the urls: https://ibb.co/fXvLtVX](https://ibb.co/fXvLtVX)

From that particular URL I need this address:
https://i.ibb.co/VLm5D0L/Cuadros-Decorativos-Canvas-Revolution-Principal-REC-Liquido-De-Colores.png

Which is the src attribute of the main image.

Can I automate this task using JavaScript or any other tool?

Here is a screenshot of the Excel file where contains the URLs data.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely do it with JavaScript, or [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) to make it simple.

To get a src attribute from an element in the DOM just use

```
var imageUrl = $("#image-viewer-container img").attr('src');
```

And if you have to read an excel file I suggest you to use the csv extension and just loop the links reading the file as [previously answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431565/3151134)

The problem is that if you try to get the content of a page using JavaScript only you might stumble into [No Access-Control-Allow-Origin problems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), but there are many ways to avoid this.

The most simple is probably to add a PHP file and call that with [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://link-to-your/file.php",
   data: "url=" + encodeURIComponent(url),
   success: function(data)
    {        
        var image = $('#image-viewer-container img', $(data));
        var imageUrl = image.attr('src'); 
        // Do what you have to do with the image src
    } 
});
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  

$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);

echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 1):

let me know if the following answer makes sense to you. If it does we can work on the code.

using javascript:

```
1) read in excel file (csv)
2) go to each link
3) get img.src
4) write  img.src to file
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help. It makes a lot of sense. It would be ideal that the "writing img.src" be in the same position as the links are now. Best.