# How to read User ID and Password from CSV file into a Array using Java Script

Tags: javascript

I have a CSV file as below - accounts.csv

```
User_Name,Password
TestAccount1,Passw0rd
TestAccount2,Passw0rd
TestAccount3,Passw0rd
TestAccount4,Passw0rd
```

Trying to write a JavaScript code to read them into a array variable and use it further in script like 
UserName[1] and Password [1] or may be like UserName and Password

Tried using the below code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var parse = require("csv-parse"); //installed csc-parse
var csvFile = "accounts.csv";

class User {
  constructor(user_id, user_password) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.user_password = user_password;
  }
}

const processData = (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`An error was encountered: ${err}`);
    return;
  }

  //skipping has heading row
  data.shift(); 

  const userList = data.map(row => new User(...row));

}

fs.createReadStream(csvFile)
  .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',' }, processData));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read data From \*.CSV file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below snippet :

```
const fs = require('fs');
var parse = require("csv-parse"); //installed csv-parse
var csvFile = "accounts.csv";
const userList = [];

const processData = (data) => {
    if (data != undefined) {
        //console.log(data);
        userList.push({ "username" : data[0],   "password" : data[1]});
    }
}

fs.createReadStream(csvFile)
    .pipe(parse({
        delimiter: ',',
        from_line: 2 // to skip the header row
    }, processData))    
    .on('data', processData)
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
        console.log(userList);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the shared code, it gives me output as:

`code`
[ 'TestAccount1', 'Passw0rd' ]
[ 'TestAccount2', 'Passw0rd' ] 
CSV file successfully processed 
[ 
User { User_Name: 'TestAccount1', Password: 'Passw0rd' }, 
User { User_Name: 'TestAccount2', Password: 'Passw0rd' } 
]  
`code`

What I am looking for is 2 variables, something like: 
`code`
console.log(username); 
console.log(password); 

Output: 
TestAccount1 
Passw0rd
`code`

Comment: @user127911 - You want the output like `[{ "U1" : "P1"},{"U2":"P2"}]` or You want it like `UserName & Password` in `seperate Array` ?

Comment: My objective is to read User ID and Password from CSV and use it in POST body for Login using JavaScript (as part of SiteSpeed.io scripting)

Given the post body, I am looking to have an Array (may be 1 or 2), using which I can substitute User and Password individually, somewhat like below:
`code`
ID='username' value=<UserName>
ID='password' value=<Password>

Comment: @user127911 - Modified the above snippet - Is this you are looking for ?