# Can a javascript bookmarklet read from an excel or CSV file

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Is it possible to have a javascript bookmarklet read from an Excel or CSV file?

Lets say I have an excel file of grades for a class with ID #s for each student looking similar to

```
[1,Luke,A]
[2,Leia,B]
[3,Anakin,C]
...
```

and I have to enter the grade into multiple web pages. My goal is to have a bookmarklet that I can click and it will put column 3 of this excel file into a text area.

I know it is possible to create a command box to enter data using CSV format but that data would need to be entered every time the bookmarklet runs. I am looking for something where I can store information in a temporary table that will span multiple webpages and I can refer to with the same or different bookmarklets.

Edit: Let's say the files name is currently C:\Grades.txt
I would assume the code would look something like below. Textarea will always be the first of a page.

```
Javascript:( 
function(){ 

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
URL: "C:\Grades.txt",
dataType: "text",
success: function(data) 
{
document.getElementsByTagName("Textarea")[0].value = data;
}
});
})();
```

I am still just trying to have javascript read from an external file but when I use ajax it wants to put the entire HTML code of the current webpage into the text are not what is in the .txt file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript

Comment: Regardless of whether it's possible or not from a bookmarklet, I don't think Excel files can be read. I know CSV can, because it's just plain text.

Comment: What function should I be looking into for referring to a CSV file?