# Import a csv file in my program Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

What i would like to to is import a csv file in my program knowing it's path.

For example if the path to the csv is `C:/Users/User/example.csv` I would like to somehow load this in my program, something like:

```
let MY_CSV_FILE =CSV_LOAD("C:/Users/User/example.csv")
```

I don't care about writing to it or reading from it, just loading it.

How could this be done in javascript?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7431268/13464279) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read data From \*.CSV file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tags you selected, I am assuming you want to read your CSV data into your Node app. You need a package like `node-csv`. You can then use `csv-parse` to load you CSV data.

Install it first

```
$ npm install node-csv
```

And then read your file like this:

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
const parse = require('csv-parse');
const parser = parse({columns: true}, (err, records) => {
    console.log(records);
});

fs.createReadStream("C:/Users/User/example.csv").pipe(parser);
```