# how can i import data from csv file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv

i want to import this numbers from csv file :

Likes:

1

24

4

into a js table:

data1=[];

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read data From \*.CSV file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript)