# How to convert plain set of data from the file into json format

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, text, formatting

I have some plain machine learnig data set in separate lines like this:

vhigh,vhigh,2,4,small,low,unacc

vhigh,vhigh,2,4,small,med,unacc

vhigh,vhigh,3,more,med,low,unacc

*... 1700 more lines like above*

I want to convert data into structure like this:

```
[
  {
    "buying": "vhigh",
    "maint": "vhigh",
    "doors": "2",
    "persons": "2",
    "lug_boot": "small",
    "safety": "low",
    "evaluation": "unacc"
  },
  {
    "buying": "vhigh",
    "maint": "vhigh",
    "doors": "2",
    "persons": "2",
    "lug_boot": "small",
    "safety": "med",
    "evaluation": "unacc"
  },
...

]
```

and save converted data into new file.json

#edit : Node.js runtime

Comment: The question lack context, are you in a browser ? Node runtime ? Other ? Dou you already have the dataset in a string variable ?
Check other questions related to CSV parsing in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Did you look into parsing CSV text,? What environment are you going to run this on? SO is not a code writing service where you can dump your requirements like this.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the runtime - its node.js
I wanted to use the regex

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Thank you for targeting the csv. It was enough to use the conversion tool here: https://csvjson.com/csv2json

After conversion:
[image: csv converter]

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good option when you need to transform large chunk of data or format your data in the background. I would rather look for some [transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_duplex_and_transform_streams) that would [read input line by line](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) and write formatted data into output.