# How can I create a new CSV file with the row and column numbers from each cell in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a `csv` file, without the header information [1]. Each cell contains some values, then read all rows, then save the cell values, as well as, the accompanying row and column numbers, in a separate csv file, in *JavaScript*:

[image]
[Download the file](https://uploadnow.io/f/fmxX5yd)

Additionally, I would like to get the result below in a new csv file:

```js
row     column    value

1            1            0.704191104

1            2           0.424829561

1            3          0.009920801

....

12           1         0.337513255

12           2         0.435984561

....

12           7         0.546245968
```

The following code has a bug. Your help to fix it would be highly appreciated.

```js
RawData = d3.csvParse(
  await FileAttachment("datafile.csv").text(),
  d3.autoType
)
d3 = require('d3-dsv')
```

Comment: This should assist you, best... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript